# Where to put Visual Studio and SQL Server databases - SSD or HDD?

Tags: laptop, ssd, development

Lenovo Thinkpad W520 - Add 128GB or 256GB Vertex 4

I am going to get an ultra-bay for the current HDD for mass storage and data overflow.

**I am looking at the best way to setup the OS and applications.**

Going to run Windows 7, Visual Studio, Sql Server Express, and Expressions among other smaller less intensive apps.

1. General rule of thumb, what should be on the HDD to save space on the SSD?
2. Should the sql db files (three around 4GB each) be on the HDD or SSD?
3. Are there any file types that will not matter which drive they're on?

Thanks!

Comment: If you can configure your SQL Server to use a lot of RAM - you can put big database on HDD and impact on performance will be not that bad. Unless your application works on huge data amounts.

Comment: Visual Studio is very efficient and well optimized, if you put it on SSD it will load faster but... don't expect huge performance improvement after it is loaded. Location of .NET libraries is more important (`C:\Program files\ReferenceAssemblies`). But if you are C++ programmer and you are not using .NET SDK a lot - put it on HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things you want to read and write faster should go on the SSD.

If you require good read and write performance to the SQL database then you should put it on the SSD, if on the other hand you don't really case about the performance (since this is a development machine), you could probably just put the SQL files on the hard drive.

Putting Visual Studio on the SSD would probably make it load up faster.